# Recent responses page interprets time in a strange manner

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

I'm located in UTC+03. When I open "recent responses" page at about 5PM (my local time) it behaves strange.

For example, right now, when I just open it - it lists "2009-12-08 14:17:03Z to 2009-12-08 23:59:59Z, the current time is 2009-12-08 14:23:16Z" and "nothing to report" but when I click "Today" it lists "2009-12-08 00:00:00Z to 2009-12-08 23:59:59Z, the current time is 2009-12-08 14:25:24Z" and a handful of responses in the corresponding time frame.

In the first case it clearly lists a very short period of time - from "five minutes ago" to "midnight" and nothing falls into that range.

That looks strange. The interface clearly doesn't allow me to look into the future, only into the past. Then what is the period it displays when "recent responses" is clicked?

Comment: You have **17PM** and now you want to see the future too?

Comment: I no longer have that.

Answer (score 1):

These two fields on your user profile might provide some clues to this mystery:

- seen
- last activity (only visible to you and moderators)

Comment: Why is the behaviour described in the question only reproduced in the evening? "Current responses" showed all responses during the day.

Comment: Those two fields would indeed provide some clues... if the behavior were consistent. Unfortunately, it is randomly weird.